# Where does py_modules go in pyproject.toml (setuptools)

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

Where does the `py_modules` parameter (I don't know what it is called) go in a `pyproject.toml` file?

```ini
[project]
name = "elements"
version = "1.0.0" 
description = "Magic"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.10"

license = {file = "LICENSE"}
authors = [
  {name = "x"},
  {name = "y"}
]

maintainers = [
  {name = "x"},
  {name = "y"}
]

[project.scripts]
stuff = "stuff:__init__"


[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["baseclasses", "elements"]
# this raises error. 
py_modules = ["__init__"]

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=43.0.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

My project structure looks like this:

```bash
.
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── baseclasses
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── bunch_of_py_files.py
├── elements
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── bunch_of_py_files.py
├── pyproject.toml
```

I have tried to put it under the `project` section and the `tool.setuptools` section, but both raised the `project must not contain {'py_modules'} properties` error.

I was looking through setuptools and pip docs, but the only thing I could find was for `setup.py` files, which I read was [being deprecated](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html) and as such didn't want to use.

Comment: `__init__.py` has to be inside a directory, and that directory will then be an "[*importable package*"](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package)". It cannot be at the root of the project (i.e. next to `pyproject.toml`). -- Also per convention your project should have one and only one top-level importable package or module with the same name as the project itself. And in your case, there are at least 2 importable packages: `baseclasses` and `elements`. You should consider turning `baseclasses` into a subpackages of `elements`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the solution [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html)

```ini
[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["baseclasses", "elements"]
py-modules = ["__init__"] # dash, not underscore
```